# Connecting Viewsonic Monitor to PC with Ubuntu 20.1

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get a 2nd Viewsonic monitor to work on an old pc with Ubuntu 20.04.2. The pc is a Lenova ThinkCentre-M92P wth Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2). I bought a USB 3.0 to vga adaptor to hook up the monitor. But when I opened the package I found the adaptor has a Windows driver cd. Can I make all this work together?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you plugged it in and looked in display settings?

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I open Settings/Displays I only get adjustments for the first monitor. It is not recognizing the second monitor on the usb port.

Comment: Does `lsusb` offer any info about the device?

Comment: Is that a terminal command? I have rarely used terminal.

Comment: Yes. Plugin the device, open the terminal, and run that command. Look for any output about your monitor or graphics in general. You can also just edit your post to add the complete output (use the code tags).